# Using stl in an Android adb shell native program

Tags: stl, android-ndk, adb

I'm trying to port a C++ utility program that I want to be run from the Android ADB shell.
For that, I'm using the Android NDK's make-standalone-toolchain.sh script, and compiling my program with it.
Unfortunately, when I try to run it, I get this error:

```
reloc_library[1315]: 16304 cannot locate '_ZNKSs5c_strEv'...
CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE
```

After some research, I saw that this means that the c_str function doesn't exist in libstdc++.so in the NDK. I also couldn't find the symbol in stlport.so either, and actually only found it in the ./sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/libs/ version of the C++ libraries. These libraries are not included in the standalone toolchain I made, and I also couldn't find them on the device (the device is running Honeycomb).

The text in the NDK clearly states that there's support for the entire STL when I use stlport. Is this something that is only true in Ice Cream Sandwich? The libstlport.so or in libsupc++.so on the device and in the NDK didn't have any signature like the one that wasn't found.

So my question has two parts:

1. Is there something I'm missing in the build process/Android setup? Can I set up things differently so that the program will compile without needing the gnu-libstc++, or at least fail with a compilation/link error instead of failing to load on the device?
2. If linking with gnu-libstc++ is the only way, how can I do that? I think I can manage statically link to it but I'd rather not.

How can I add the gnu-libstdc++ version to my

Comment: To select different STL implementation (like static stlport or static gnustl) use APP_STL variable in Application.mk file (read docs/CPLUSPLUS-SUPPORT.html file).

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do that, since I'm using the standalone toolchain and in general I'm not compiling an activity, but rather a linux program that I plan to run on the adb shell (similar to ps or cp)

Comment: Then examine how ndk-build is selecting STL implementation (it chooses specific CFLAGS and LDFLAGS). Select same compiler and linker flags for your standalone toolchain and you'll be able to select static STL library.

Answer (score 0):

If someone else is looking for a solution, I ended up adding a dependency using the -l switch on libgnustl_shared.so. You can find it inside the NDK at

```
sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/libs/<architecture>/
```

I then pushed this .so together with the program to the device, and made a script that adds the current directory to LD_LIBRARY_PATH. It seems similar to what the NDK does when you use the make scripts to create a program that depends on gnustl.